# Are f and f' independent when using Euler–Lagrange equation?

Tags: partial-derivative, independence, euler-lagrange-equation

[According to this wikipedia](http://Calculus_of_variations#cite_note-CourHilb1953P184-1), in section **Euler–Lagrange equation**, in  the first example  (shortest path between two points), it says

> $${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial L}{\partial f}}-{\frac {d}{dx}}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial f'}}=0}$$
>
> with
>
> $${\displaystyle L={\sqrt {1+[f'(x)]^{2}}}\,.}$$￼
>
> Since f does not appear explicitly in L , the first term in the
>   Euler–Lagrange equation vanishes for all f (x) and thus,
>
> > $${\displaystyle {\frac {d}{dx}}{\frac {\partial L}{\partial f'}}=0\,.}$$￼

..

I am confused. Are `f` and `f'` independent so that the first term in the Euler–Lagrange equation **vanishes** for all f (x)?

In short, why is 
 $${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial L}{\partial f}}=0}$$ where $${\displaystyle L={\sqrt {1+[f'(x)]^{2}}}\,.}$$ ?

As  $${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial L}{\partial f}}={\frac {\partial f'}{\partial f}}×{\frac {\partial L}{\partial f'}}}$$, does this mean that  $${\displaystyle {\frac {\partial f}{\partial f'}}=0}$$ ?

Thank you in advance for making it clear for me.

Comment: You don't need to think of them as variables like that. $L$ is a scalar function of two scalar variables and its partial derivatives are taken with respect to those variables. The identity of the variables only matters after you have already assembled the E-L equation.

Comment: To put it another way, $L=L(y,v)$ and the E-L equation reads $L_y(f(x),f'(x))=d/dx[L_v(f(x),f'(x))]$.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your quick reply.. Mmm, do you mean that L is not a functional, but a scalar function, and f and f' are not functions but variables? And could you explain what y and v are?

Comment: L is not a functional in this context; it takes two scalar arguments and returns a scalar. I write $y=f(x),v=f'(x)$ to emphasize that.

Comment: @Ian Maybe I would have to take a look at the The induction process of Euler-Lagrange equation

Comment: Not really, you can take it as a black box. The only confusing thing is that we often conflate the Lagrangian at a given point in phase space with the Lagrangian of a trajectory; the latter is the integral of the former along the trajectory.

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/580858/11127 , https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1798396/11127 and links therein. Related Phys.SE question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/885/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Right it was.

Comment: @Ian Thanks! Something is trying to come into my mind. Also I got words that call what I wondered from the comment below.